# The program does not stop at the function (while true loop) in Python

Tags: python

this is my first time asking question in this forum. If there are mistakes in posting this question, please mention it.

I am doing a menu function by using Python. In the code, I used def to classify the functions like keypad and what to display. The following is the code:

```
#import
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

def main():    
  # Initialise display
  lcd_init()
  definition()
  while True:
        lcd_string("Press any key to",LCD_LINE_1)
        lcd_string("continue",LCD_LINE_2)
        keypad_init()
        key_pad()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        menu_page()
        key_pad1()
        time.sleep(0.5)

def keypad_init():
  for j in range(4):
        GPIO.setup(col[j],GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(col[j],1)

  for i in range(4):
        GPIO.setup(row[i], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

def definition():
  global row
  row=[2,3,4,17]
  global col
  col=[27,22,10,9]
  global MATRIX
  MATRIX=[[1,2,3,'A'],
        [4,5,6,'B'],
        [7,8,9,'C'],
        ['Yes',0,'No','D']]
def key_pad():
  # Keypad Function
  while True:
        for j in range(4):
                GPIO.output(col[j],0)
                for i in range(4):
                        if GPIO.input(row[i])==0:
                                return
                                while(GPIO.input(row[i])==0):
                                        pass
                GPIO.output(col[j],1)

def key_pad1():
  # Keypad Function
  global pagecount
  while True:
        for j in range(4):
                GPIO.output(col[j],0)
                for i in range(4):
                        if GPIO.input(row[i])==0:
                                pagecount = MATRIX[i][j]
                                return
                                while(GPIO.input(row[i])==0):
                                        pass
                GPIO.output(col[j],1)

def menu_page():
        lcd_string("1.Diagnose",LCD_LINE_1)
        lcd_string("2.BMI Calculator",LCD_LINE_2)

def option_choose():
  if pagecount ==1:
        lcd_string("Diagnose Start!",LCD_LINE_1)
        lcd_string(" ",LCD_LINE_2)
  if pagecount ==2:
        lcd_string("BMI Calculate!",LCD_LINE_1)
        lcd_string(" ",LCD_LINE_2)

def lcd_init():
  # Initialise display
```

The problem is that the program does not stop at key_pad() and key_pad1(). It just keep on looping and change the things to be displayed. I want to display "Press any key to continue" until a key is pressed. Please help me with the problem. If the question is not clear, please state them. Thank you very much. Ps. I am using Raspberry Pi for the hardware part

Comment: Can you leave only the relevant bits of your code? I'm guessing all the constants and definitions are irrelevant to the essence of your question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: ok, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `while True` loop to wait a key press, you can use `GPIO.add_event_detect` method :

```
def keypad_init():
    for j in range(4):
        GPIO.setup(col[j],GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(col[j],1)

    for i in range(4):
        GPIO.setup(row[i], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(row[i], GPIO.BOTH, callback=keyPressed)

def keyPressed:
    # Do your action here
```

You can also use `GPIO.event_detected()` method, depending on what you want to do.
Take a look at https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/

Comment: GPIO.event_detected() should be put at the function that used as an interrupt?

Comment: No, you doesn't have to use `GPIO.event_detected()` inside the callback function of `GPIO.add_event_detect`. It is two different manner to catch an event. Take a look at the examples on the GPIO documentation.